# I want to find group count but code says no match found

Tags: java, regex-group

This is my code; why am I getting false as my first output and group count as 0.Thanks

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT. Your class should be named Solution. */
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = "a";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("a");
        Matcher matcher = p.matcher("car");
        boolean b = matcher.matches();
        System.out.println(b);
        System.out.println("Number of matches : " + matcher.groupCount());
    }
}
```

Comment: `Pattern.compile("(a)");` https://regex101.com/r/fMUpsf/1

Answer (score 0):

The pattern "a" does not match the input "car".  You might mean a pattern like  ".*a.*".  Or perhaps use the `find` method.

Once you've fixed that:

You have no explicit [groups](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) in your regex.

Per [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#groupCount()), group 0 (the whole regex) is not included in the matching group count.

Therefore the group count is 0.